# Help with chinese address

Tags: translation, names, place-names

I would like to ask for help in "decoding" chinese name and address that seller gave me to return the item back to china. I tried translators on the internet but they do not work. The street address is most important for me. It would be highly appreciated if someone could help me.

Recipient: Xie Dong Fang-H

Street address: **TianFuDaDaoBeiLu 1700Hao, Huan QiuZhongXin E1 1Dong 2DanYuan 1601Hao**

City: cheng du shi

Voivodeship: si chuan sheng

Country / Region: China

Zip: 610015

Comment: I input the address in Google Maps and it says it’s 天府大道.

Comment: 1700 Tianfu Avenue North Road

Worldwide center E1

Building 1

Unit 2

Floor 16

Number 5

Chengdu

Sichuan province

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TianFuDaDaoBeiLu 1700Hao, Huan QiuZhongXin E1 1Dong 2DanYuan 1601Hao

天府大道北路 1700號， 環球中心 E1 1棟 2單元 1601號

City: cheng du shi

City: 成都市

Voivodeship: si chuan sheng

Province: 四川省

Country: PRC (China)

Zip: 郵編610015